# Apache SSL handshake interrupted by system

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-ssl

I have an up-to-date `Ubuntu 12.04` server running `Apache 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4`.
For every HTTPS request my Apache logs record what appear to be error messages related to encrypted connections.

Self-signed certificate was generated based on instructions from [Ubuntu 12.04 » Ubuntu Server Guide » Security » Certificates](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html)

[Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) shows no problems with the server config(other than self-signed cert).

Relevant section of Apache config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName site.domain.net:443
  ...snip...
  SSLEngine             on
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
  SSLProtocol           all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder   on
  SSLCompression        off
</VirtualHost>
```

Error logs are showing entries similar to this:

```
[Wed Feb 19 10:47:01 2014] [info] [client xx.xx.61.4] Connection to child 2 established (server site.domain.net:443) 
[Wed Feb 19 10:47:01 2014] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy 
[Wed Feb 19 10:47:01 2014] [info] [client xx.xx.61.4] (70014)End of file found: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!] 
[Wed Feb 19 10:47:01 2014] [info] [client xx.xx.61.4] Connection closed to child 2 with abortive shutdown (server site.domain.net:443)
```

Browser is not hitting <kbd>Stop</kbd> button as the log implies.

Why am I getting these errors, what do they mean and how to stop them?

Comment: What _are_ you seeing in the browser?

Comment: Do you set `SSLSessionCache` to value different with default value?

Comment: @MichaelHampton afaik everything appears to work correct.
@Gnouc nope. it's only set in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf` and I have not changed it from the default.

Comment: Do you get more information if you set `LogLevel debug`?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman hmm after enabling `debug` now I don't seem to be getting these errors anymore. :/ I'll keep watching it..

Comment: It looks like https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52703 might be your issue.